# How to implement iADs into application in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

How can I implement iADs into application in iPhone? i downloaded more than 4 sample codes but no one shows even iADs block in application.
how to show ADBannerView programmatically
anyone provide step by step for showing iADs programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

```
ADBannerView *adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 366, 320, 50)];
adView. requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
adView.delegate = self; 
[self.view addSubview: adView];
```

Edit: Thanks go out to @LucasTizma.

Comment: i paste this code in viewdidLoad method the last line generate error i modified this line with [self.view addSubView: adView]; its build successed but not seen any iADs block in simulator

Comment: Well obviously you can't just paste this code and expect it to work. You'd need to change it to fit your application.

Comment: That last line should read `[self.view addSubview:adView]` assuming you want to just add the banner view you just created.